# Setting up a DoubleClick Floodlight on a click

Tags: javascript

I am new here and I am trying to do something theoretically simple but I am just not getting it right. I need to fire a DCM Floodlight tag on a click event. The issue I am having is that there is already a Google Analytics function wrapped in the href element so when I am testing the tag I am getting the GA tag to fire, but not the Floodlight.
The below is what I am using

[image]

```js
<a href="http://www.iac2017.org/site/DefaultSite/filesystem/documents/IAC-2017-Registration-Brochure-2017.pdf" target="_blank" class="button" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'Document', 'Download', ''); onclick="Registration brochure('land01','iac_f000','testu1');">DOWNLOAD REGISTRATION BROCHURE</a>
```

Do you guys see anything wrong with my syntax?

Aprreciate your help

Answer (score 2):

Instead of adding another `onclick` attribute, you need to combine both function calls within the same attribute, like so:

```
<a href="http://www.iac2017.org/[...]/IAC-2017-Registration-Brochure-2017.pdf"
  target="_blank" class="button"
  onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'Document', 'Download', ''); brochure('land01','iac_f000','testu1');">
  DOWNLOAD REGISTRATION BROCHURE
</a>
```

*Note:* I've put this on multiple lines just for readability, it is fine to have it as one line.

I'm assuming here that the function you're trying to call for the brochure is called `brochure()` and not somehow `Registration brochure()`, as spaces don't work within function names.

Also, I'd like to mention that using `onclick` attributes for JavaScript is generally not encouraged any more. It's better to use DOM event listeners to separate JavaScript from the HTML, an approach named [Unobtrusive JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript).

Comment: Thanks +Glodenox, unfortunately the onclick attribute is still not working. It might something to do with the function. I will double check and see what might be causing the issue.
Thanks again

Comment: No problem! I'd advice to look in the web console for any errors at the moment you click the button. You may want to replace the href attribute's value with `#` first, as your page will reload otherwise. Alternatively, you can probably disable the clearing of logs at page unload in your browser.